# How to use saved model with C++ in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, visual-studio-2019

First Here is my environment.

**System information**
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Windows10
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): tensorflow/tensorflow
TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.4.0
Python version: 3.7.5
Bazel version (if compiling from source): 3.1.0
GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source):
CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA 11.0.2 / cuDNN8.0.5.39
GPU model and memory: RTX3090

I compiled tensorflow source and get 'tensorflow.dll' and 'tensorflow.lib'.
So I tried below code succesfully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
    return 0;
}
```

Next, I tried to load the h5 pretrained model after saving it(saved_model.pb) in python. There is a c++ header needed for that, but when I tried to load it, a link error occurred in vs2019.

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h"
```

**-Question-**

1. How to set visual studio directory(include, library) for using bazel compiled output?
   I don't know what folder,dll,lib and header to use.

- bazel-bin
- bazel-out
- bazel-tensorflow
- bazel-testlogs
  [image]

2. I tried to use 'tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h' for using saved model. When I add needed header, vs2019 keep saying linking error
   `fatal error C1083: cannot open include file. 'Eigen/Core': No such file or directory`
   So I manually added path to include dir. But I got this error.
   `fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024`
   Is this a problem caused by setting the include and library directory paths incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

**I figure out there is no need to add additional header in code.

But still don't find the manual that show how to use TF c version.

The information below is simply a combination of information I found on the Internet.**
(I installed cuda and cudnn version which showed in bottom of below link. )
(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows?hl=ko)

1. First download tensorflow-gpu c precompiled version
   (https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.6.0.zip) -> you can modify version in link like 2.4.0.zip.
2. Download tensorflow code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
3. Make new project in Visual Studio 2019(I also succeed in 2022).
4. In the downloaded libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.6.0.zip file, copy the tensorflow folder inside the include folder to the Visual studio project (location where the cpp file is located).
5. Unzip the tensorflow-master.zip file downloaded from Github.
   Paste the files in tensorflow-master\tensorflow\c into the unzipped file into the visual stdio project tensorflow\c folder.
6. Paste the files in tensorflow-master\tensorflow\core\platform into the tensorflow-master.zip file downloaded from Github into the visual stdio project tensorflow\ folder.

Then you can run the example code in tensorflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
  return 0;
}
```

**Here is functional code which read .csv file(11x11 float) and output the class probability.**

- I used gpu memory growing option which use the minimum gpu memory that model requires.(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <format>
#include <filesystem>

void NoOpDeallocator(void* data, size_t a, void* b) {}

TF_SessionOptions* CreateSessionOptions(double percentage) {
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_SessionOptions* options = TF_NewSessionOptions();

    // the following is an equivalent of setting this in Python:
    // config = tf.ConfigProto( allow_soft_placement = True )
    // config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    // config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = percentage

    // create a byte-array for the serialized ProtoConfig, set the mandatory bytes (first three and last four)
    uint8_t config[15] = { 0x32, 0xb, 0x9, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x20, 0x1, 0x38, 0x1 };

    // convert the desired percentage into a byte-array
    uint8_t* bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&percentage);

    // put it to the config byte-array, from 3 to 10:
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(percentage); i++) {
        config[i + 3] = bytes[i];
    }

    TF_SetConfig(options, (void*)config, 15, status);

    if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Can't set options: " << TF_Message(status) << std::endl;

        TF_DeleteStatus(status);
        return nullptr;
    }

    TF_DeleteStatus(status);
    return options;
}

int main() {
    //********* Read model
    TF_Graph* Graph = TF_NewGraph();
    TF_Status* Status = TF_NewStatus();

    TF_SessionOptions* SessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
    TF_Buffer* RunOpts = NULL;

    const char* saved_model_dir = "odm_CNN_smallcut_best\\"; // Path of the model
    const char* tags = "serve"; // default model serving tag; can change in future
    int ntags = 1;

    TF_Session* Session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(CreateSessionOptions(0.3), RunOpts, saved_model_dir, &tags, ntags, Graph, NULL, Status);
    if (TF_GetCode(Status) == TF_OK)
    {
        printf("TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel OK\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s", TF_Message(Status));
    }
    //****** Get input tensor
    int NumInputs = 1;
    TF_Output* Input = (TF_Output*)malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * NumInputs);

    TF_Output t0 = { TF_GraphOperationByName(Graph, "serving_default_conv2d_input"), 0 };
    if (t0.oper == NULL)
        printf("ERROR: Failed TF_GraphOperationByName serving_default_input_1\n");
    else
        printf("TF_GraphOperationByName serving_default_input_1 is ..................OK\n");

    Input[0] = t0;

    //********* Get Output tensor
    int NumOutputs = 1;
    TF_Output* Output = (TF_Output*)malloc(sizeof(TF_Output) * NumOutputs);
    TF_Output t1 = { TF_GraphOperationByName(Graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall"), 0 };
    if (t1.oper == NULL)
        printf("ERROR: Failed TF_GraphOperationByName StatefulPartitionedCall\n");
    else
        printf("TF_GraphOperationByName StatefulPartitionedCall is OK\n");
    TF_Output t2 = { TF_GraphOperationByName(Graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall"), 0 };
    if (t2.oper == NULL)
        printf("ERROR: Failed TF_GraphOperationByName StatefulPartitionedCall\n");
    else
        printf("TF_GraphOperationByName StatefulPartitionedCall is...................OK\n");

    Output[0] = t1;
    //Output[1] = t1;

    //********* Allocate data for inputs & outputs
    TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumInputs);
    TF_Tensor** OutputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumOutputs);

    int ndims = 4;
    int64_t dims[] = { 1, 11, 11, 1 };
    int ndata = sizeof(float) * 11 * 11; // This is tricky, it number of bytes not number of element
    
    int SIZE = 11;
    float* data = (float*)malloc(SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(float));
    int file_num = 1;
    while (true) {
        //********* File Open
        std::string InputfileNameNext = "input\\" + std::to_string(file_num + 1) + ".csv";
        std::ifstream fileNext(InputfileNameNext);
        std::string InputfileName = "input\\" + std::to_string(file_num) + ".csv";
        std::ifstream file(InputfileName);
        if (fileNext.fail()) {
            Sleep(1);
        }
        else {
            //********* Read Data
            if (file.is_open()) {
                std::string line;
                int row = 0;

                while (getline(file, line) && row < SIZE) {
                    std::stringstream ss(line);
                    std::string cell;
                    int col = 0;

                    while (getline(ss, cell, ',') && col < SIZE) {
                        data[row * SIZE + col] = std::stof(cell); // Convert string to float
                        col++;
                    }

                    row++;
                }
                file.close();
            }

            TF_Tensor* int_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, ndims, data, ndata, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
            if (int_tensor != NULL)
            {
                //printf("TF_NewTensor is OK\n");
            }
            else
                printf("ERROR: Failed TF_NewTensor\n");

            InputValues[0] = int_tensor;

            // //Run the Session
            TF_SessionRun(Session, NULL, Input, InputValues, NumInputs, Output, OutputValues, NumOutputs, NULL, 0, NULL, Status);

            if (TF_GetCode(Status) == TF_OK)
            {
                //printf("Session is OK\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s", TF_Message(Status));
            }

            //finish = clock();
            //duration = (double)(finish - start);

            void* buff1 = TF_TensorData(OutputValues[0]);
            float* offsets1 = (float*)buff1;

            //********* Result File
            // Open a text file in write mode
            std::string OutputfileName = "output\\" + std::to_string(file_num) + ".txt";
            std::ofstream outFile(OutputfileName);
            // Check if the file opened successfully
            if (!outFile) {
                std::cerr << "Unable to open file for writing." << std::endl;
                return 1;  // Exit with an error code
            }
            std::string a = "[" + std::format("{:e}", offsets1[0]) + " " + std::format("{:e}", offsets1[1]) + "]";
            outFile << a << std::endl;
            // Close a text file
            outFile.close();
            printf("%d Finished..WAITING...\n", file_num);
            file_num = file_num + 1;
        }
    }
    // //Free memory
    TF_DeleteGraph(Graph);
    TF_DeleteSession(Session, Status);
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(SessionOpts);
    TF_DeleteStatus(Status);

    free(data);
    free(Input);
    free(Output);
    for (int i = 0; i < NumInputs; i++) {
        free(InputValues[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOutputs; i++) {
        free(OutputValues[i]);
    }
    free(InputValues);
    free(OutputValues);

    return 0;
}
```